# testthat failure using check()

Tags: r, package, environment, devtools, testthat

I'm trying to add some testing to my package to make sure that things remain as they should when I make changes. I'm having some difficulties in doing this.

I want to test the main function of my package, which can be roughly described as an imputation method. So if I give an `n x 2` matrix `Y` to it where the second column has some `NA`, it should return `Z` where the first columns in `Y` and `Z` are the same (because it's completely observed) and the second column should be imputed so that there are no `NA` in the second column of `Z`.

Obviously, there are several other inputs to the function, but the main structure of my test is

```
context("Test output")
test_that("First column equal", {
  set.seed(100)
  Y <- matrix(rnorm(200), 100, 2)
  Y[seq(1, 100, by = 3), 2] <- NA
  out <- my_fun(Y)
  expect_equal(Y[, 1], out[, 1])
})
```

My problem is that this doesn't work. It works when I run `devtools::test()`, but not when running `devtools::check()`. I tried using `expect_equal_to_reference()` (because what I really want to test is bigger and more compelx than this example), but it also throws an error, despite running the code in the console and comparing to the saved `.rds` file shows that they are identical.

I found this quote by Hadley ([under tests](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/check.html)):

> Occasionally you may have a problem where the tests pass when run
>   interactively with devtools::test(), but fail when in R CMD check.
>   This usually indicates that you’ve made a faulty assumption about the
>   testing environment, and it’s often hard to figure it out.

It doesn't bode well, but what can I do? Any ideas?

Here is the error I get (`test_file` is the name of the file containing the above code):

```
checking tests ...
** running tests for arch 'i386' ... ERROR
Running the tests in 'tests/testthat.R' failed.
Last 13 lines of output:
  3: asNamespace(ns)
  4: getNamespace(ns)
  5: tryCatch(loadNamespace(name), error = function(e) stop(e))
  6: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
  7: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
  8: value[[3L]](cond)
... 13 lines ...
  5: tryCatch(loadNamespace(name), error = function(e) stop(e))
  6: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
  7: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
  8: value[[3L]](cond)

  testthat results ================================================================
  OK: 0 SKIPPED: 0 FAILED: 1
  1. Error: First column equal (@test_file.R#12)
```

Comment: To try any debugging a simplified `my_fun()` (but still failing the test) would be useful.

Comment: @m-dz I understand that, but that function is quite intricate and the entire package (more or less) just consists of the building blocks for it. I know it's a long shot to ask the question without it, but my hope is that someone's experienced something similar before.

Comment: Maybe try (after https://github.com/hadley/testthat/issues/86): "Simply add `Sys.setenv("R_TESTS" = "")` as the first line in `tests/testthat.R`".

Comment: @m-dz I feel almost ashamed, but I had just forgotten to load the package also in the test file. I was pondering removing the question, but I'll let it be in case anyone else makes a similar brainfart in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is as embarrassing as it is simple. The package needs to be loaded in the test file, so that it should start with:

```
library(mypackage)
context("Test output")
```

While I thought that it worked before, it actually did not. Now that the package is loaded properly, I can see that e.g. the progress bar printed by `my_fun` appears in the Build pane.